# Forking with multithread will make unreachable stack memory in the child process

Tags: linux, multithreading, fork

If a process with multi-thread forks, then other threads' stack memory will be copied but unreachable. I think this will make some waste of memory. (Because the child threads aren't copied)

```cpp
//This code describes that the copied unreachable stack exists in the copied child process.
//The variable 'buf' has different values in both processes.

int sig;
int global;
int *ptr;
void proc()
{
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread_start, NULL);
    while (ptr == NULL);
    pid_t pid = fork();
    sig = 1;
    usleep(100000);
    if (pid)
    {
        printf("Process Response: %d, %p, %d\n", pid, ptr, *ptr);
        global = 1;
        int status;
        wait(&status);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Process Response: %d, %p, %d\n", pid, ptr, *ptr);
        global = 2;
        exit(0);
    }
}

void *thread_start(void* data)
{
    int buf = 135;
    ptr = &buf;
    while (sig == 0);
    buf = 999;
    sig = 0;
    while (global == 0);
    printf("Thread Response: %d\n", global);
    return NULL;
}
```

Moreover, if the child thread allocates a large memory in the heap, the waste of memory will be critical.
Just I shouldn't write programs like that?

Comment: Usually when you fork, it's immediately followed by an exec to load a new process so it doesn't matter. If you're using a different workflow for some reason... even then it probably won't matter. Is it impacting your ability to allocate memory in the child process?

Comment: `fork` does not copy threads (in the sense of executing code), only the thread that called `fork` is copied. It doesn't copy memory as well. There's this thing called "copy on write". Meaning there will not be a memory leak because your child process won't be aware of what parent threads do. But yes, mixing threads with fork asks for trouble: http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them

Comment: Are you asking about any particular operating system? I remember when it used to be the case that allowing a Linux program to `fork()` after it had created new threads was a _Bad Thing._ But, Linux is always changing, and I don't know how it is these days.

Comment: Is it bad thing to using fork without exec? What I'm worrying about is that fork without exec will make unused memory copied. Even though there's "copy on write", if the parent process frequently modify the unused (by child) memory, there should exist the modified memory and unused unmodified memory. The problem about copied stack memory is one of these.